# Concatenation of aggregate function and string attribute

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to do query like this:

```
select wm_concat(some_attribute1) || some_string_attribute || wm_concat(some_attribute2)
from SomeTable;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You should only be able to do that if there is a group by

```
select wm_concat(some_attribute1) || some_string_attribute || wm_concat(some_attribute2)
from SomeTable
group by some_string_attribute;
```

or if the 2nd part is also an aggregate

```
select wm_concat(some_attribute1) || max(some_string_attribute) || wm_concat(some_attribute2)
from SomeTable
group by some_string_attribute;
```

But I don't think it will work as you have shown since you are mixing aggregate with non-aggregate, akin to

```
select product, sum(price) from sometable
```

*(i.e. which product since there is no group by)*

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select
    wm_concat(attribute_the_first) colNameWon,
    the_agregation_attribute,
    wm_concat(attribute_the_second) colNameToo
from
    table_mien
group by
    the_agregation_attribute
```

If you get the results you want (in 3 columns), then the string concatination will give you what you seek.